# tz_localize based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        time=pd.DatetimeIndex([
            '2018-10-28 01:30:00',
            '2018-10-28 02:00:00',
            '2018-10-28 02:30:00',
            '2018-10-28 02:00:00',
            '2018-10-28 02:30:00',
            '2018-10-28 03:00:00',
            '2018-10-28 03:30:00']), 
        zone=np.random.choice(['Europe/Madrid', 'Europe/London', 'Europe/Paris'], 7)
    )
)
```

I want to apply tz_localize row-wise, something like:

```py
df.assign(
    time_localized=df.time.dt.tz_localize(df["zone"])
)
```

it returns

```
TypeError: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

how can I apply row-wise tz_localize?

I am also interested in doing the reverse operation, moving from UTC to each of the time zones in the rows.

Thanks!

Comment: @BENY what do you mean by "Almost can not do that"?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity glad you find a way doing that~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure there's a vectorised way to do this, might have to use `apply`:

```py
df.assign(
    time_localized=lambda df: df.apply(
        lambda row: row["time"]
        .tz_localize(row["zone"], ambiguous=True),
        axis=1,
    )
)
```

which gives

```
                 time           zone             time_localized
0 2018-10-28 01:30:00  Europe/London  2018-10-28 01:30:00+00:00
1 2018-10-28 02:00:00  Europe/Madrid  2018-10-28 03:00:00+01:00
2 2018-10-28 02:30:00  Europe/London  2018-10-28 02:30:00+00:00
3 2018-10-28 02:00:00   Europe/Paris  2018-10-28 03:00:00+01:00
4 2018-10-28 02:30:00   Europe/Paris  2018-10-28 03:30:00+01:00
5 2018-10-28 03:00:00  Europe/London  2018-10-28 03:00:00+00:00
6 2018-10-28 03:30:00   Europe/Paris  2018-10-28 04:30:00+01:00
```

For the reverse operation, change `.tz_localize(row["zone"], ambiguous=True)` to `.tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert(row["zone"])`

Comment: And if I want to do it the other way rond? Assuming time is in UTC, what will be the time per row?

Comment: then change `.tz_localize(row["zone"], ambiguous=True)` to `.tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert(row["zone"])`

Comment: @DavidMasip just be careful about `2018-10-28 01:30:00`, which happens twice in Europe/London because that's when the daylight savings time transition happens, see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html

Comment: I'm aware, thanks for the answer!